# Wireguard is not working: 'wg0' is not a WireGuard interface

Tags: linux, vpn, ufw, wireguard

I've got an issue with wireguard. I have a debian-based VPS, and a Manjaro client.
Here is my `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf` of a server:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.1/24
ListenPort = 194
PrivateKey = <ServerPrivateKey>
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

[Peer]
PublicKey = <ClientPublicKey>
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2/32
```

Here is my `/etc/wireguard/wg0.conf` of a client:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.0.2/32
PrivateKey = <ClientPrivateKey>

[Peer]
PublicKey = <ServerPublicKey>
Endpoint = <ServerIP>:194
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
```

Here is my `ufw status` output:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
143                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
993                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
51820                      ALLOW       Anywhere                  
IMAPS                      ALLOW       Anywhere                  
POP3                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
SMTP                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
194                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
143 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
993 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
51820 (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
IMAPS (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
POP3 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
SMTP (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
194 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

Here is my `lsmod | grep wireguard` output:

```
wireguard              94208  0
curve25519_x86_64      36864  1 wireguard
libchacha20poly1305    16384  1 wireguard
ip6_udp_tunnel         16384  1 wireguard
udp_tunnel             20480  1 wireguard
libcurve25519_generic    49152  2 curve25519_x86_64,wireguard
```

After `wg-quick up wg0` and `wg-quick down wg0` on a server I've got this error:
`` wg-quick: `wg0' is not a WireGuard interface ``
I'm sure, the mistake was on my side. But where was I mistaken?

Comment: I solved this issue by changing port to default wireguard one (194 was already used) and by changing interface form `eth0` to `ens3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, I do not have enough reputation to comment yet. Have you tried a different port for Wireguard on your server? Typically, ports within the lower range from 0 to 1023 are used by the linux OS, although I do not know if 194 is used for something specific already. But you could try one in the upper ranges like 51820 which is already open in your firewall, or if you use that already try 51819 and don't forget to open it in your firewall.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Yeah, I solved this issue by changing port to default one and by changing an interface from eth0 to ens3